# Opportunity attacks during flying on a mount

Tags: dnd-4e, mounted-combat

According to DMG p.47 on the FLY: MOVE ACTION

> **No Opportunity Attacks:** A flying creature cannot make opportunity
>   attacks

This makes sense to me, so if a character is flying (e.g. using 'Winged Boots') he cannot make opportunity attacks.
**However if the character is on a mount, does he still get the opportunity attack, or is he considered as flying as he has to command his mount?**

Answer (score 1):

This has been eratta'd and is no longer true.

Flying creatures can now take opportunity attacks, so the question is irrelevant.

This section of text is missing from both The RC text (p 210), and the text in the [online compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=367) which references both of these sections. Were this still true it would greatly reduce the effectiveness of numerous monsters and an entire PC race (Pixie), as well as numerous paragon paths and several Epic Destinies.

So to answer the question, yes, if you're flying on a mount you get your opportunity attack (you even increase the number of squares you threaten typically as you threaten all of your mounts adjacent squares.